# Why is my grid area resizing when I add text?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Been trying to make a fancy new website and came across this - the other divs are resizing when content is added.

How it should look: A rectangle divided into 2 thirds, with one double the size of the other.

[image: A rectangle divided into 2 thirds, with one double the size of the other]

How it looks: A rectangle divided into 2 fifths, with one quadruple the size of the other containing text:

[image: A rectangle divided into 2 fifths, with one quadruple the size of the other containing text]

Nothing else I found online works. CSS code below if it matters.

```css
/* basic styling above */
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "  ";
  height: 600px;
}

#work {
  grid-area: ;
}
#thing {
  grid-area: ;
}
```

Already fixed thanks to Hao Wu. (Editing for discovery purposes)
All I needed was `css grid-auto-columns: 1fr`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Your text implies on 2 columns but you have defined 3 areas and there is no `grid-template-columns` rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify the proportion for each column. If you want the  area to take 2/3 of the space, try adding `grid-auto-columns: 1fr` to your grid layout. So all the columns are taking the equal spaces.

```css
#container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "  "
    ;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
    height: 600px;
}
#work {
    grid-area: ;
    background-color: salmon;
}
#thing {
    grid-area: ;
    background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="work">
    <h1>Work.</h1>
    <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
  </div>
  <div id="thing">
    <h1>Thing.</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The default width of a column in a grid is `auto`. That means the grid column will expand or shrink if needed.

To have a 2:1 split you should use: `grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr` which will split the columns equally in 2 fractions and 1 fraction.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  gap: 1em;
}


/* For visualization purpose only */
.container > div {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  min-height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>2/3 block</div>
  <div>1/3 block</div>
</div>
```